# Don't reset section counter after part

Tags: sectioning, counters, parts

Is there a way to preserve the current section counter to continue its counting, independent from the parts separating them?

```
\part{Part 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}

\part{Part 1}
\section{Section 4, not 1}
```

Comment: The default behaviour is for `\section` counters to not reset with every part when using the default `article` document class. So you must be using a different class, correct? Regardless, the linked duplicate points to different packages/methods you can use to change the behaviour.

Comment: I am actually using koma script. So the class is scrartcl. Sorry for not telling that.

Comment: Either way, under `scrartcl` the `\section` counter is not reset with `\part`. So you must be doing something else that's not disclosed here.